# How do I get access to the CSS Editor

Tags: css, visual-editor, code, design

I have a blog which is hosted by an ecommerce company who also host my website and online store. Because of this, they uploaded the theme I requested - Penscratch. I couldn't do it myself. I now want full access so that I can edit the design of the blog fully. At the moment, within the dashboard area, I have minimal access to the appearance of the theme - general colours, adding a header image etc. But I can't change colours of specific bits of text, change the width of the page, play around with page design etc. 
My hosting company say they won't let me have full access as they don't give out ftp details and I will have to ask them for every change I want (which will probably cost me.)

So my question is - is there a way around this? Can I access everything without needing to have their ftp details? And as I haven't used wordpress.org before, I'm not sure what the dashboard SHOULD look like. I have nothing to compare it to, so I don't know if I'm being shown a watered down version.

Any advice is appreciated.

Thanks
Dan

Answer (score 1):

Without being rude, it will probably cost more to fix what you break instead of asking them in the first place! - however, you can't learn until you break!.

If I were you and you are interested in trying to play around with CSS/HTML - then you could always install Wordpress locally on your Mac/PC, there are plenty of guides around & Videos on youtube.

But to answer part of your question, yes, if they make you an admin in the dashboard area, under 'Appearance' there's an editor button - and that should allow you to change theme files and CSS files without FTP access however:  ** BIG WARNING: changing these files without a site backup or FTP access is risky and can result in your blog/site breaking if you do something wrong! **